# How to get coordinates from GPS instead of from triangulation antennas in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager

I'm using CLLocation mechanism to get coordinates in iPhone. I took an example from "Locate me" example and extended it a little bit. However I'm issuing accuracy problems.

- If I set desired accuracy to 10 meters or less I get response with accuracy 1414 meters.
- If I set desired accuracy to 100 or more - the best accuracy I get is 65 meters in most 
  cases. Sometimes more sometimes less.
- If I turn off WiFi and 3g i get accuracy ~47 meters.

So the question is, is there a way to make iPhone to get location using GPS instead of triangulation antennas?

It would be nice to know if there is a way to improve accuracy when using antennas but the best result I got till now is 65 meters.

Comment: Is this the final accuracy you get, or the first one? Because the point of the location manager is to abstract away from you the mechanism of how it is getting the location, and just give you the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't really supposed to be trying to control what hardware is getting the location for you. If you want greater accuracy, you can check the accuracy given to you by the `CLLocation` and throw it out if it's not what you want.

Alternatively, you can take a bunch of readings and average them with this code I wrote! You pass an array of `CLLocation` objects to it and it returns one, averaged location. I use it in one of my apps and it gives great accuracy (usually within a meter if you use >5 locations).

```
- (CLLocation *) averageLocations: (NSArray *) loci
{
    double tempLat=0,tempLong=0,tempAlt=0,tempAccH=0,tempAccV=0,tempCourse=0,tempSpeed=0,tempTime=0;
    for (CLLocation *loc in loci)
    {
        tempLat += loc.coordinate.latitude;
        tempLong += loc.coordinate.longitude;
        tempAlt += loc.altitude;
        tempAccH += loc.horizontalAccuracy;
        tempAccV += loc.verticalAccuracy;
        tempCourse += loc.course;
        tempSpeed += loc.speed;
        tempTime += loc.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate;
    }

    double ratio = (double) loci.count;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D tempCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tempLat/ratio, tempLong/ratio);
    NSDate *tempDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:tempTime/ratio];

    CLLocation *temp = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:tempCoord 
                                  altitude:tempAlt/ratio 
                        horizontalAccuracy:tempAccH/ratio 
                          verticalAccuracy:tempAccV/ratio 
                                    course:tempCourse/ratio
                                     speed:tempSpeed/ratio
                                 timestamp:tempDate];

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Wow accuracy of one meter is a great measure. I'll try your code.

Comment: I have a bunch of other code too, but it's mostly to throw out inaccurate locations and limit the update speed. I didn't think you needed/wanted 6 pages of location processing code.

Comment: I used your code to improve accuracy. Looks like sometimes it gives me better results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Core location wont give you location data with the datasource. The best way to guarantee location is to look for the date of the CLLocation object you receive, and to check the location horizontal and vertical accuracy. I have worked extensively with core location and I can tell you that if you need accurate location data, the time is a very good indicator of inaccurate information. If i need accurate data, i would disregard data older than 5 seconds.

Comment: Yep it is good indicator to be one of reasons for inaccurate data. Using this alone with some other tricks (like calculating average, thanks Dustin) will much improve accuracy.